# Como usar la funcion query de DynamoDB

Tags: nodejs, express, aws

estoy estudiando un poco de AWS lambda y DynamoDB, quiero crear un CRUD sencillo con estas tecnologías usando express. En un endpoint quiero hacer una consulta a la DB para buscar a un usuario con un email que recibo por el body, la consulta la hago de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
await db.query({
   TableName: 'user',
   KeyConditionExpression: "email = :email",
   ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":email": email
 }
}).promise()
```

pero veo los logs en CloudWatch y me dice lo siguiente:
`ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: userId`
entiendo que espera que mande el id del usuario, pero en este endpoint no hay forma de recibir el id.

`db` es una instancia de DynamoDB.DocumentCLient, estoy usando el modulo `awas-sdk`.